# How do I manage development, test and production environments for Android?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app and am not sure how I should manage development, test and production environments/builds.

For example I have an API string that I use for development; for test and production this string is different.  Where should I put this in my Android project and how do I manage which one is used?

Comment: What about different git branches? That's what I use.

Comment: @Alex can you explain more?  What would be preferred to a string?

Comment: Dis you find a solution? I am not sure how to accomplish it with Android, any hep would be really appreciate :)

Comment: In case you didn't, this should work for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961231/android-eclipse-switching-between-debug-and-release-for-xml-file

Answer (score 0):

If you use version control system, like Git, you can just have different branches with your different values. For example, I use two different URL's for my Android app's API: `localhost:3000/api/bla` and `www.mysite.com/api/bla`.

I have a main branch that I use for development and uses my localhost server, and a production branch I use that has the actual website. I update the main development branch with new features, bug fixes, etc. and when I need to, I merge those changes into the production branch.