# Android Eclipse Switching between debug and release for XML file

Tags: android, eclipse, config

I have an XML file that contains some config data for my Android App. In it there is config info that can be used for development and production. E.g. the link to our api can be set as follows:

For production:

```
<api>api.example.com</api>
```

For development:

```
<api>dev.example.com</api>
```

I keep this config file under /assets/app-config.xml

It is quite a hassle to keep having to remember which setting I have in the XML. Is there a way to automatically configure eclipse/ android so that it uses the production for runtime (export etc.) and the development when in debug mode.

Comment: Can you post your query clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define multiple resources and use `BuildConfig.DEBUG` to conditionally get a resource or another:

```
<string name="url_api">api.example.com</string>
<string name="url_api_dev">dev.example.com</string>
```

When extracting the resource:

```
getString(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? R.string.url_api_dev : R.string.url_api);
```

This constant is set to `true` as long as you run from Eclipse. When you select the *Export Signed Application Package* option, it will be set to `false`.

If you use this method, it is a good idea to be aware of [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27940).

Comment: Looks like a great solution if it wasn't for the "little" bug you mention. I can see google have not solved it yet.

Comment: Yeah, it's a really nasty bug. But this is the reason why you test your APK before publishing. As an extra warning, include some Toast message stating "This is a DEBUG build" when your app launches that only shows when `BuildConfig.DEBUG == true`, so *AT LEAST* you know when you get affected by the bug.

Comment: This bug is the reason I have a written checklist of things to do when exporting release builds.  I like the pop-up idea too.  And in my apps I always have a string showing the version number and whether it is a release or debug build.

Comment: Overall it looks like a good direction. Facebook requires a facebook_app_id defined in strings.xml. How can I then place 2 different ids (prod/dev) as these are being read by a third party

Comment: @checklist AFAIK, you don't need to. At least, when I was developing an app with a "Log in with facebook", the same FB app ID was working for debug AND production.

Comment: We use 2 different facebook apps for each env

Comment: Then Idon't think it's possible... You'd need a -debug modifier, and AFAIK that soesn't exist... :/

Comment: I suggest to encapsulate this into an abstract class. What I do is to inject the context to a static method in order to retrieve the resource. To accomplish this I use the getIdentifier() method as this answer proposes http://stackoverflow.com/a/3538784/844451

Answer (score 0):

Customize your build using ANT

Please refer the following link for more information 
http://playaprogrammer.blogspot.com/2013/01/android-build-configuration-tutorial.html

I use this to create test and production builds from single source. You can have different configurations for development, QA, Production...